# How do I put the removed word into a variable?

Tags: python

so I have been making a memory game in which a 3x3 grid is displayed, and is removed after 30 seconds. After, another 3x3 grid is displayed but one of the words from the first grid has been replaced with another word. The user has to guess the original word that has been replaced. However I am unsure how to code this.
here is my code:

```
import random # imports the random module, to generate the words
import time  # imports the time module, used for the countdown
try:
    with open ('patrick star.txt') as f: # opens the text file
    words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f], 9)
    grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)] # puts the words into a 3x3 grid
    for x,y,z in grid:
        print (x,y,z) # prints the 3x3 grid
except IOError:
    print("The code does not seem to be working")
time.sleep(30) # displays it for 30 seconds
import os
os.system('cls') # this function clears the screen after countdown

print("Time's up!")


try:
    with open ('patrick star.txt') as f: # opens the text file
    words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f], 9)
    grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)] # puts the words into a 3x3 grid
    for x,y,z in grid:
        print (x,y,z) # prints the 3x3 grid
```

Comment: Could you fix your indentation please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You will have to change the part where you read the words from a file and 'clear'/'cls'

```
import random
import time, os
from string import ascii_letters

os.system('clear')
# make twenty random words
random_words = [''.join(random.sample(ascii_letters, 5)) for i in range(20)]

# select 9 from the random words and make grid
words = random.sample(random_words, 9)
grid = [words[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(words), 3)]

for x,y,z in grid:
    print x, y, z

time.sleep(5)
os.system('clear')

ri = random.randint(0, 8)  # random index

# save the old word
old_word = grid[ri // 3][ri % 3]

# replace with new random word
grid[ri // 3][ri % 3] = random.sample(random_words, 1)[0]

# print again
for x, y, z in grid:
    print x, y, z

g = raw_input(">> Enter old word that changed:\n")
if g == old_word:
    print "You won!"
else:
    print "No!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first rewrite it slightly in a skeleton similar to this:

```
import random

class Board(object):
    board = [[[""],[""],[""]],[[""],[""],[""]],[[""],[""],[""]]]
    hide = ()
    guess = ()

    _size = 0
    _words = []

    def __init__(self, words, size = 3):
        self._size = size
        self._words = words

    def populateBoard(self):
        sample = random.sample(self._words,self._size**2)
        i = 0
        for x in range(self._size):
            for y in range(self._size):
                self.board[x][y] = sample[i]
                i += 1

    def guessWord(self,x,y,word):
        return board[x][y] == word

    def hideWord(self):
        pass

    def displayBoard(self):
        pass

    def awaitAnswer(self):
        pass


with open ('patrick star.txt') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

b = Board(words)
```