# Cannot identify randomly removed word from a grid

Tags: python

I'm doing a school project where two 3x3 grids of words from 'words.txt' are printed. The user has to guess the removed word however I can't get the bit where you say the question is right. It prints `unlucky` every time, even if you win!

The words.txt file is set out like this and there are 10 words and 9 are printed in each grid:

```
SMOKE    
FUNNY    
CHAIR    
PRICE
```

My code currently is as follows:

```
import random

with open ('words.txt') as f:
    words = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],9)
    grid = [words[i:i + 3] for i in range (0, len(words), 3)]
    for x, y, z in grid:
    print x, y, z

import time
time.sleep (20)

import random

with open ('words.txt') as f:
    words2 = random.sample([x.rstrip() for x in f],9)
    grid2 = [words2[i:i + 3] for i in range (0, len(words2), 3)]
    for x, y, z in grid2:
    print x, y, z


removed_word = words2
user_guess = (input('What word has been replaced?')).upper()

if user_guess != grid2 and user_guess == removed_word:
    print ('You win')

else:
    print ('unlucky')
```

Comment: see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28947410/1268926

Comment: `with open(...` repeats twice in your code. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes it is should it only be once?

Answer (score 1):

```
if user_guess != grid2 and user_guess == removed_word:
```

You are trying to compare `user_guess` (string) to `grid2` (list). And then compare string to `words2` which is a list. Those two conditions will never be `True`.

[`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample)

> Return a k length **list** of unique elements chosen from the population
>   sequence.

---

I haven't check in detail your code, but you probably need to check if `user_input` is inside the lists:

```
if (user_guess not in grid2) and (user_guess in removed_word):
```

Comment: Thanks however it still always says unlucky even if you guess the correct word.

Comment: @J_Harris `user_guess` is upper case (since you use `.upper()`). I don't know your file contents but i'm guessing they are lowercase. Correct? Now that i think of it, guessing is bad. Please include a small sample of your file contents in your question.

Comment: They are all capitals and five letter words.

Comment: I think some are SMOKE, FUNNY, PRICE, GHOST, CHAIR. Also there is 10 of them of which 9 are printed in each file.

Comment: Please include a small sample of your file contents in your question. I need to see if they are on the same line, if they are separated by comma etc. Also, do your `print`s show what is expected?

Comment: I tried to debug your code but there are many problems. You might want to learn how to do this on your own, it will be invaluable later on. Use some debugger (i personally use PyCharm's debugger, but there are other options too). Alternatively, insert print statements in various places, to see what you have assigned to your variables. You ll be surprised.

Comment: Lastly, you should adjust my answer; `user_guess in grid2` to `user_guess not in grid2` or something like that.